What doesn't my button render the same across browsers?
A graphical button:

I am attempting to replicate this graphical button, I found on a website. However, unlike the website, I want to make this with CSS and have it work across all existing and popular browsers. See demo: https://codepen.io/Alix-Blaine/pen/wvLwxrN.
Replication with CSS:


main {
  margin: 0;
  width: 4.313em;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-color: #666699;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: .2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px inset rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.8);
  border-left: 2px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-right: 2px inset rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.8);
  border-top: 2px inset rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
<main>
  <a href="index.html">Twitter</a>
</main>



Results:
Chrome

Firefox


Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When you want to be sure it renders the same across ALL browsers, ironically the best approach is to use an image instead of CSS. If you still want to go down this road, take a look at this: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/create-browser-specific-css

@Paulie_D, please see my edit. Thanks.

Different browsers can render slightly differently, which is why you are seeing the differences in your example. As Wimanicesir said, an image would be an easy implementation to guarantee consistency of the look.

This question asks too much of answerers, while providing little in the way of evidence of research. For instance, so me, those two screenshots look pretty darn close to the desired outcome. So close, I'd need a pixel ruler and a color picker to investigate the differences. So close I'd say we'd spend more money twiddling with CSS getting any closer and if we need that level of perfection, we should go with an image.

@HereticMonkey thanks, but, inset shadows or border not showing well under Chrome.

This interface problem dates back to the beginnings of wysiwyg and the "war" over Adobe font licenses; and your font-size: 0.75em; will never be the same, even if you use a true Type font.

That's the kind of detail that should be [edit]ed into the question. That's what @Paulie_D meant when he asked you to "clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need". We need to know what you see are the specific problems with each browser's representation of the CSS in order to suggest different CSS, along with the hacks that will get them to display for just that browser.

BTW nobody cares that it's not exactly the same on all browser. Users don't decide whether or not to use a site because of that.

I would use vector, such as .svg, to achieve the same over-all result and keep it crispy. Like so:


<main>
  <a href="index.html"><svg
   version="1.1"
   width="67"
   height="21"
   id="svg17"
   sodipodi:docname="stack.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.3.2 (091e20e, 2023-11-25, custom)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs17">
    <rect
       x="43.82093"
       y="43.378296"
       width="306.74652"
       height="124.82326"
       id="rect19" />
    <rect
       x="45.591473"
       y="51.345737"
       width="297.45117"
       height="102.24884"
       id="rect18" />
    <rect
       x="49.575195"
       y="60.198448"
       width="279.3031"
       height="84.986046"
       id="rect17" />
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview17"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#000000"
     borderopacity="0.25"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
     inkscape:zoom="10.245981"
     inkscape:cx="21.179036"
     inkscape:cy="9.2231284"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="974"
     inkscape:window-x="-11"
     inkscape:window-y="-11"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg17" />
  <rect
     style="display:inline;fill:#666695;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.526527"
     id="rect20"
     width="66.461639"
     height="20.436222"
     x="0.26530051"
     y="0.30037344"
     inkscape:label="rect20" />
  <path
     d="M 0.00265149,0.03543588 C 2.3997226,1.103814 1.2578846,4.0660316 1.5494423,6.111032 c 0.038134,4.430444 0.064893,8.860978 0.088974,13.291518 21.2684991,0.01725 42.5369981,0.03451 63.8054971,0.05176 0,-6.00452 0,-12.0090405 0,-18.0135608 0.456894,-0.2027749 1.591792,-1.96109364 1.549498,-1.01858235 0,6.86082175 0,13.72164315 0,20.58246515 -22.324502,0 -44.649004,0 -66.97350624,0 C 0.01415367,14.0149 0.00840258,7.0251679 0.00265149,0.03543588 Z"
     fill="#6b6973"
     id="path3"
     style="display:inline;stroke-width:0.128795;fill:#292833;fill-opacity:1" />
  <path
     d="M -0.00743854,9.2933662e-4 66.997645,1.68604e-4 C 66.485559,0.47038005 65.498313,1.5512629 65.498313,1.5512629 64.056495,1.7539709 2.6794333,1.7514905 1.6690757,1.7124055 c 0,0 -1.67651424,-1.49780952 -1.67651424,-1.71147616338 z"
     fill="#ababab"
     id="path4"
     style="display:inline;stroke-width:0.128795;fill:#aaaaaa;fill-opacity:1"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
  <path
     d="M 0.00265149,0.03543588 C 0.58814053,0.55946512 1.1232929,1.1364982 1.6599176,1.7095289 c -0.00128,5.8940224 -0.00255,11.7880451 -0.00383,17.6820671 -0.5511443,0.531928 -1.10228854,1.063855 -1.65343281,1.595783 -1.1e-6,-6.983981 -2.2e-6,-13.9679621 -3.3e-6,-20.95194312 z"
     fill="#33334a"
     id="path5"
     style="display:inline;stroke-width:0.128795;fill:#595972;fill-opacity:1" />
  <text
     xml:space="preserve"
     id="text19"
     style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:93.3333px;line-height:1.2;font-family:'Times New Roman';-inkscape-font-specification:'Times New Roman, ';white-space:pre;shape-inside:url(#rect19);display:inline;fill:#ffffff;stroke:none;stroke-width:4.15748"
     transform="matrix(0.12984378,0,0,0.12775574,-2.1493329,-1.2609385)"><tspan
       x="43.820312"
       y="123.89016"
       id="tspan1">Twitter</tspan></text>
</svg></a>
</main>



